# MLR: Function "predict.WrappedModel" not found

Tags: mlr

I am using R 3.6.1, RStudio 1.2.5019 and mlr 2.15.0. Mlr ist installed and loaded. Only mlr and the packages mlr is built on are loaded.

Now, I have trained a model using `train` and would like to test it on new data. 
Therefore, I want to use the `predict.WrappedModel` function from mlr.

If I call
`?predict.WrappedModel` I get all the information in the help window.

However, if I want to run `predict.WrappedModel` R throws an error indicating that the function cannot be found:

`my_test = predict.WrappedModel(object = my_model, task = my_task)`

> konnte Funktion "predict.WrappedModel" nicht finden

Even when specifying mlr as the package to look in for the function:

`my_test = mlr::predict.WrappedModel(object = my_model, task = my_task)`

> Fehler: 'predict.WrappedModel' ist kein von 'namespace:mlr' exportiertes Objekt

I also tried using `?predict` , but here I also got an error:

`my_test = mlr::predict(object = my_model, task = my_task)`

> Fehler: 'predict' ist kein von 'namespace:mlr' exportiertes Objekt

I've already spent a lot of time trying to fix this issue and read all the related questions I had found here and on the mlr forum on github, but could not find a solution.

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please? In general, you should always use `predict` and don't need to use the `predict.*` functions directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neither need `predict.WrappedModel` nor `mlr::predict`. Both are internal functions using the generic S3 approach in R to operate based on the class of the supplied R object.

So in this case, as long as you pass a object derived from a `mlr::train()` call everything will just work.

Speaking with code:

```r
library("mlr")
my_model = train(learner, task)
predict(my_model, task)
```

Comment: I thought that there is a mlr-specific `mlr::predict` function (just like there is a mlr-specific `mlr::train` function), but that seems to be not the case. Instead, we just use the regular `train` function from the stats library.
This misunderstanding has led me to wanting to use the mlr-specific `predict.WrappedModel` function, which I was unable to run, and posting my question.

Comment: @TimoK Yes, `train()` is indeed not a S3 function in this case and can be called using `mlr::train()`. Such confusions are better handled in _mlr3_. Also when a question is answered on Stackoverflow, please click the green check mark so it is marked as "solved" (and optionally you can upvote the answer if you liked it).